# EF Core creating an async call for HTTP PUT

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

Can I get some guidance on how to make these functions async? Run table record delete, then, insert new data EF Core 2.2 - I am running into concurrency issues.

1. `Routing_Tool_SO4` is the main table that only gets updates
2. `Routing_Tool_Services` records are erased and new items are added every time.

RoutingToolController:

```
[HttpPut("updateSO4")]
public IActionResult UpdateSOJ4([FromBody] Routing_Tool_SO4 routing_Tool_SO4)
{
    Routing_Tool_SO4 request = new Routing_Tool_SO4();
    request.Id = routing_Tool_SO4.Id;
    request.Routing_Tool_Services = routing_Tool_SO4.Routing_Tool_Services;
    request.When = routing_Tool_SO4.When;
    request.Where = routing_Tool_SO4.Where;
    
    // needs to run first to erase secondary table 
    _repository.UpdateServiceSOJ4(request.Id);

    // then update main table
    _repository.UpdateSO4(request);

    return Ok(request);
}
```

`IRoutingToolRepo`:

```
void UpdateServiceSO4(object routing_Tool_Service);
```

`RoutingTool.cs`:

```
// run first to erase records on secondary table
 public void UpdateServiceSO4(object routing_Tool_Service)
 {
     var Id = new SqlParameter("Id", routing_Tool_Service);
     var sql = _context.Routing_Tool_Service.FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Routing_Tool_Service WHERE Routing_Tool_SO4Id = @Id", Id).ToList();

     if (sql != null)
     {
        _context.Routing_Tool_Service.RemoveRange(sql);
        _context.SaveChanges();
      }
}
    
// run to update only the records on the main table  
public void UpdateSO4(object routing_Tool_SO4)
{ 
      _context.Update(routing_Tool_SO4).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Start at the bottom. Mark the two `UpdateXxx` calls async, make them return a `Task` and `await SaveChangesAsync` in them. Them work up the stack, marking each call `async`, having them return a `Task` or a `Task<T>` and `await`ing them as well

Comment: Making this all async won't fix concurrency issues.